# Extracting coordinates from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Consider the following: `"MULTILINESTRING((10 10,10 40),(40 40,30 30,40 20,30 10))"`.
I want to transform this into: `[[10,10],[10,40],[40,40],[30,30],[40,20],[30,10]]`.

**My solution**
I use the functions `split()` and `replace()`to format this. I get some dirty code and probably not the most efficient like `my_str.split('((')[1].split('))')[1]...etc`

Because I'm doing this on a huge dataset, I'm looking for an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for clean code that doesn't do too much, I'd recommend a two step process involving the `re` module—

1. split your string into smaller chunks on comma using `str.split`
2. for each chunk, extract coordinates with `re.findall`

For performance, I'd recommend pre-compiling a regex-pattern using `re.compile`, since we'll be calling it repeatedly inside a loop.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
>>> [list(map(int, p.findall(x)) for x in mstring.split(',')]
[[10, 10], [10, 40], [40, 40], [30, 30], [40, 20], [30, 10]]
```

Note, *`mstring`* is your string data.

---

**Details**

```
\d+    # match one or more digits
(?:    # specify non-capturing group
\.     # literal period/decimal
\d+    
)?     # optional
```

Semantically, this regex will match integers OR floats (Ajax1234's solution currently only accounts for integers, and is guaranteed to be finish searching in fewer cycles).

Comment: Thanks you. I combined your solution with the @Ajax1234 solution to get something fine.

Comment: @Nazan No, this should stand on its own. Does it work on your own data as is? I would not recommend combining two answers unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Solution of @Ajax1234 is working fine. But as you said "I'd recommend pre-compiling a regex-pattern using re.compile, since we'll be calling it repeatedly inside a loop." which Ajax didn't do.

Comment: @Nazan one solution may work fine, but another may work finer. Why not test both out on your data, and pick the one that works the best for you.

Comment: I'm currently testing the both on the whole dataset. I was testing on a reduce dataset for test purpose before.

Comment: your solution is 7% faster than Ajax solution.

Comment: @Nazan Thanks, precompiling always improves performance. Happy coding.

Comment: @Nazan By the way, for a speed boost; if you can guarantee that your coordinates are integers, you can replace the regex `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` with `\d+`, because the latter looks for ints OR floats (if you let it look for floats only, it'll become a lot faster).

Comment: I would like to point out that your regex only return positive numbers (it removes the `-` ). I changed it to `r'\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?'` and it's working in my case. According to you is that correct ?

Comment: @Nazan Yes, perfectly. If you're only looking for integers, you can drop the non-capture group as well.

Comment: Wow, you answered so fast. Good to know but I'm currently working with floats. Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
s = 'MULTILINESTRING((10 10,10 40),(40 40,30 30,40 20,30 10))'
final_result = list(filter(None, [list(map(int, i.split())) for i in re.findall('[\d\s]+', s)]))
```

Output:

```
[[10, 10], [10, 40], [40, 40], [30, 30], [40, 20], [30, 10]]
```

Comment: Working fine, I just need to delete the first cell of my array which is empty. Thanks you.

Comment: @Nazan Glad to help. Please see my recent edit, as I added a way to remove empty lists from the result.

Comment: It looks a lot worse after the edit now. I highly doubt this is going to be more readable or better than what OP currently has. @Nazan you may want to consider breaking this up into multiple lines if you insist, or see my answer for an alternative.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, the original did indeed work fine, but it seems that the OP was running into empty lists generated from his dataset. This updated solution handles the empty lists.

Comment: Yes, but you iterate over re.findall, I iterate over str.split.

Comment: But to be fair, we're only making assumptions without OP's data here. Your solution works fine for the MCVE given ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ True, it is not immediately clear what the dataset looks like. Still, +1 for `re.split`.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Wait, _you_ upvoted? Why, thank you, returned :) Btw, sorry, that was a typo... I meant `str.split`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you :) BTW, I am not familiar with the `?:\.` portion of your regex. If you could write a brief explanation of that, I would be grateful.

Comment: @Ajax1234 no problem. I've edited my answer. The regex basically looks for ints OR floats. I assume this would slow things down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171120/discussion-between-ajax1234-and-cs).